# Keeping firebase connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, connection, keep-alive

I building a Chat for Android OS and I want to be connect to firebase for all time. My proposal is to implement a background service that detect a disconnection from firebase and reconnect after disconnection.
My code of the service:

```
public class FirebaseConnection extends Service {

DatabaseReference connectedRef;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {

  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

  connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected"); 
  connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
  @Override 
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) { 
  boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class); 
  if (connected) { 
  System.out.println("connected"); 
  } else { 
  connectedRef.goOnline(); 
  System.out.println("not connected"); 
  } 
  } 

 @Override 
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { 
 System.err.println("Listener was cancelled"); 
 } 
 });

   return START_STICKY;
 }
 @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return mBinder;
  }
  }
```

This solution not enough, I see that for short period it reconnect after disconnection but after several hours it fail to reconnect and the connection ends.

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Don't try to keep a database connection alive when the app is not active. While it may work when you build it, it will likely fail on other devices (if not now, then in a future Android version). When an app is not active, it should not keep network connections open. To communicate with an app while it is not active, use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I can implement periodic goOnline for keep connection?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK will always try to maintain an open connection to your Firebase Realtime Database instance.  If the connection is broken, it will automatically try to reconnect.

There is no need to do any maintenance on that connection.  It's handled for you.

Comment: But if I use background service the firebase doesn't reconnect

Comment: The firebase try to reconnect only if the firebase listener is in foreground

Comment: Android has the right to stop your application from using network resources if the user isn't using it.  This helps the user save data.  Instead, use FCM if you want to notify your app if of new data, then use that to load new data in response to the message.

Comment: You sure that android can stop Internet connection, because I wonder how Whatsapp works?

Comment: If I use background service and implement periodic goOffline and immediatly after that goOnline function. I can get continuous connection? Example: For all 10 minutes pass I use goOffline and after that goOnline?

Comment: Firebase online/offline has nothing to do with Android's choice to block an app's network connections.

Comment: If android stop the connection how Facebook and Whatsapp works?

Comment: Read my comment above about FCM.  Also consider AlarmManager and JobScheduler.

Comment: Fcm is not reliably enough

Comment: After all my attempts to keep firebase connection, nothing work. Somebody can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an xmpp server implementation;

I strongly suggest you look into these;

for server implementation
https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-server-demo

for client implementation
https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-client-demo

Tried them, they work

Comment: You know how I keep the connection with firebase?